# Azure cosmos db emulator macOS - Win32Exception/CoreCLR

Tags: macos, azure-cosmosdb

I have downloaded the docker image `azure-cosmos-emulator:latest` on macOS(BigSur). It starts up fine but when I try to load it in the browser(`https://localhost:8081/_explorer/index.html`), I'm getting 2 errors in the logs.

```
% docker run -p 8081:8081 -p 10250-10255:10250-10255 -e AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_PARTITION_COUNT=3 -e AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_ENABLE_DATA_PERSISTENCE=TRUE -e AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_IP_ADDRESS_OVERRIDE=$ipaddr -it mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator:latest
This is an evaluation version.  There are [90] days left in the evaluation period.
    Starting
    Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x8007000E
    Started 1/4 partitions
    Started 2/4 partitions
    Started 3/4 partitions
    Started 4/4 partitions
    Started
    
    Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
       at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common.ProcessUtil.Run(String fileName, String args)
```

1. Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x8007000E
2. Win32Exception

Can anyone help?